# AWS EstimatedCharges always 0

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I'm using the cloudwatch "EstimatedCharges" to see how much I have spent. However, I find that the value is always 0. I have definitely enable this metric. I have two account and one is returning correct values and another is 0. So my procesure should not be wrong. Does anyone have any idea what could possibly go wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have your accounts linked (the main is paying the other)?

Comment: we do have this mechanism. However, I used the main account yesterday to check the value. It's still 0. I also tried to use cloudwatch api to see the value. It's 0 too.

Comment: We used this mechanism at my old company so I know it can work, can you provide more details?